# Move focus/navigate, with d-pad, between LinearLayouts in same fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a fragment containing several layout that I want to move the focus between. The app is operated with a **remote containing a D-Pad** (up,down,left,right & enter).

Both "view groups" are wrapped in a FrameLayout because the second one i overlapping the first one which is stretching the whole page. The views layout looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="contentSurfaceWrapper">
  <HorizontalScrollView android:id="contentSurfaceScroll">
    <LinearLayout android:id="contentSurface">
      <!-- This layout is populated with child layouts (LinearLayout) programmatically -->
      <!-- Those layouts are: clickable, focusable & focusableInTouchMode -->
    </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout android:id="navButtonsWrapper">
  <ScrollView android:id="navButtonsScroll">
    <LinearLayout android:id="navButtons">
      <!-- This layout is populated with child layouts (LinearLayout) programmatically -->
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Image of how it looks:

[image]

I'm able to navigate to the view: contentSurface and between all its childs with the remote from the action bar in the top of the app. But, now **I want to navigate from the first view (contentSurface) and its childs to the second view (navButtons) and its childs**. But I doesn't seem to be able to move the focus some how. I want the focus to be moved when reaching bottom in the first layout and back when reaching top in the second layout.

I've tried to make the children in the second layout also clickable, focusable and focusableInTouch but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. I solved it this way:

For the first child in both views, which I append programmatically, I'm setting an ID.
This ID is then used with android:setNextFocusDownId on the items in last row in top layout and in android:setNextFocusUpId on items in bottom layout on first row.

This way I can switch focus in between the childs in both views.

More info about android:setNextFocusUpId etc.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html